# Accessing a class constructor variable in another class' function

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class that's behind an interface.  We'll call it `DoStuff` and it looks like this:

```
public class DoStuff : IDoStuff
{
    private int _stuffId; //class variable

    public DoStuff(int stuffId)
    {
      _stuffId = stuffId;
    }
    ...
}
```

In another class, we'll call it `Home`, there is button logic that looks like this:

```
public partial class Home : Form
{
   private readonly IStuffPresenter _presenter;

   public Home(DoStuff doStuff)
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      _presenter = new StuffPresenter(doStuff);
      homeText.Text = doStuff.HomeText;
   }

   private void showLater_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

      int stuffId = //???
      .....
      showLater.Arguments.Add(string.Format("<StuffID>{0}</StuffID>", stuffId)); //how it's being used
   }
```

I am using `stuffId` in the `DoStuff` class and I want to be able to use it here without having to write all of the code associated with getting the ID again.  How can I access the `stuffId` from the `DoStuff` class inside of my button click event in my Home class (which is a form)?

Comment: your field `_stuffId` is private and thus visible inside your class `DoStuff`. You can't access it outside of your class. You can either make it public or you can declare a public property for the same field.

Comment: There is no where near enough information here. If you want to access any properties in DoStuff then you need an instance of it, and you should pass that to your Home form... somehow, all depends on where you are creating it etc.

Comment: there is plenty of information

Comment: @RadioSpace So what instance of `DoStuff` should be accessed in `Home`?  Where should it get that instance from?

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: You still haven't shown an instance of `DoStuff`, so no one here will be able to tell you how to get it to your click function.

Comment: @LordTakkera: There is an instance now, in the constructor

Comment: the information was that there was no instance to get it from so the solution would be to make one..  oh wait the answer did that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have provided more code, the solution becomes clear.

The first part of the problem is setting the accessibility of `_stuffId` so it can be used from outside the class scope. For this I would recommend making it a public property like so:

```
public class DoStuff : IDoStuff
{
    public int StuffId { get; set; } //class property

    public DoStuff(int stuffId)
    {
      StuffId = stuffId;
    }
    //...
}
```

The next part of you problem is that you need to be able to access your instance of `DoStuff` from within your click event. With the code you have, I would suggest creating a class level variable to store this. You can then set it from the constructor, and then use it in your click event as follows:

```
public partial class Home : Form
{
   private readonly IStuffPresenter _presenter;
   private DoStuff _doStuff;//store it here so all functions can see it

   public Home(DoStuff doStuff)
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      _doStuff = doStuff;//set the class variable here so we can use it later
      _presenter = new StuffPresenter(doStuff);
      homeText.Text = doStuff.HomeText;
   }

   private void showLater_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

      int stuffId = _doStuff.StuffId;//we can access the instance here now
      //.....
      showLater.Arguments.Add(string.Format("<StuffID>{0}</StuffID>", stuffId)); //how it's being used
   }
```

Of course, it might be possible to access the value through `StuffPresenter`, but without knowing the implementation of that I couldn't say for sure

Comment: I apologize for the lack of code.  I did that intentionally but probably left too much out.  You helped me find the answer with your solution so thanks! +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your class to expose `_stuffId`.

`_stuffId` is not accessible due to it being `private`. You can wrap the variable in a property to expose it or use a property only with a private setter if you want the constructor to manage how it is set.

```
public class DoStuff : IDoStuff
{
    public int StuffId { get; private set; }    

    public DoStuff(int stuffId)
    {
        StuffId = stuffId;
    }
}
```

which will allow you to access it but not change it:

```
int stuffId = stuff.StuffId;
```

---

Alternatively you could change `_stuffId`s accessibility:

```
public class DoStuff : IDoStuff
{
    public int _stuffId;

    public DoStuff(int stuffId)
    {
        _stuffId = stuffId;
    }
}
```

but doing so will allow it to be changed

Comment: -1 Yes it needs to be accessible... but where is the instance of `DoStuff` anywhere in the question? I downvote because this just isn't enough information to get it working

Comment: yes, obviously they are trying to get `_stuffId`, but via what instance? there isn't one. Your answer only solves part of the problem, so it is not a complete answer in my opinion

Comment: I think if they posted their complete code there would be an instance of a `DoStuff`.

Comment: @hunter: I don't know... too much of an assumption in my opinion. The OP seems quite lost so I would put the money on there not being any instance

Comment: @hunter You have no idea *what* position the OP is in.  You're making blind guesses with no real basis.  That is not productive for anyone.  Why people are upvoting such a poor quality answer that doesn't actually answer this question is beyond me.

Comment: @hunter Well your "educated" guess is wrong, based on the edit.  The OP does *not* have an instance of the object where he needs the data.

Comment: @hunter You're ignoring most of the problem.  When you do that, it does tend to seem simpler.